# How can I prevent the Escape Key from closing a JFace Dialog

Tags: java, swt, jface

I would like to be able to have it so that the Escape key doesn't close a JFace dialog pop up.

In the code I have prepared you can see this behaviour by running the main method, when you press escape.

```
public class TestDialog extends Dialog
{

    private Label status;

    private String title;

    public TestDialog(Shell parentShell, String title)
    {
        super(parentShell);
        this.title = title;
        setShellStyle(getShellStyle() & ~SWT.CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShell(Shell shell)
    {
        super.configureShell(shell);
        shell.setText(this.title);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
    {
        Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        status = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
        status.setText("Hello World");
        composite.pack();
        parent.pack();
        return composite;
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createButtonBar(Composite parent)
    {
        return parent;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestDialog d = new TestDialog(new Shell(), "Test");
        d.open();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can override the dialog `public boolean close()` and return `false` to stop the dialog closing, but I can't find a way to see that the close was because the escape key was pressed.

Comment: I think that should do it for my porpoises becasue I am closing it with another method anyway so I don't need to know if it's specifically done via escape.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a key listener to the parent `Composite` control and get the `keyEvent` to match with `SWT.ESC` and write your custom code there what you want to perform when ESC key is pressed. Now it will prevent the JFace dialog from closing.

```
@Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent) {
        Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        status = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
        status.setText("Hello World");
        composite.pack();
        parent.pack();

        composite.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                String string = "";

                if (e.keyCode == SWT.ESC) {
                    string += "ESCAPE - keyCode = " + e.keyCode;
                }

                if (!string.isEmpty()) {
                    // do nothing 
                    // here I am printing in console
                    System.out.println(string);
                }
            }
        });

        return composite;
    }
```

Comment: @Link19 .. Does the above solution resolve your issue?